# Different response in postman and in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, http

So when I'm calling endpoint from postman I got response like this:

[image]

And when I'm calling same request from my angularjs service which is:

```
this.login = function (loginInfo) {

    return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost/igt/api/public/signin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'Application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        user: {
            name: "nick",
            password: "password"
        }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("err:");
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

I've got output in console like this:

[image]

which is this:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": 400,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
    "url": "http://localhost/igt/api/public/signin",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "nick",
      "password": "password"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "Bad Request",
  "xhrStatus": "complete"
}
```

Why this difference?

Comment: I'm not an expert in AngularJS, but shouldn't that be `method: 'POST', data: { user: { ... } }`?

Comment: Yes it should be but then it say me that I didnt pass valid JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the config object properties, set your http config by this

```
method – {string} – HTTP method (e.g. 'GET', 'POST', etc)
url – {string|TrustedObject}
params – {Object.<string|Object>
data – {string|Object}
headers – {Object}
eventHandlers - {Object}
uploadEventHandlers - {Object}
xsrfHeaderName – {string}
xsrfCookieName – {string}
transformRequest – {function(data, headersGetter)|Array.<function(data, headersGetter)>} – 
transformResponse –
paramSerializer
cache 
timeout
withCredentials - {boolean}
responseType - {string}
```

[Learn more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

This is the problem I think,

```
user: {
         name: "nick",
         password: "password"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your postman the input should be

```
{
 user:{
 name:"",
password:""
}
}
```

But what you are sending is

```
{
    name:"",
    password:""
    }
```

Change your angular js code like

```
user: {
   user : {
name:"nick",
password:"password"
}
}
```

it will work.

Also change the header to
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
from
'Content-Type': 'Application/json'